# E: Unable to locate package repo

Tags: software-installation, repository

```
E: Unable to locate package repo
```

this error comes after

```
sudo apt-get install repo
```

Comment: Please explain what you expected to happen ;-)

Comment: I think he expected it to download and install the package since it's a valid package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/repo, but only in xenial

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to download AOSP sources using the `repo` tool on Ubuntu 14.04, the package can't be found (had the same issue).

Google provides instructions to download the tool manually:

> To install Repo:
>
> Make sure you have a bin/ directory in your home directory and that it
>   is included in your path:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir ~/bin
> $ PATH=~/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> Download the Repo tool and ensure that it is executable:
>
> ```
> $ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
> $ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
> ```

You should now be able to run `repo init ...` and `repo sync`

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install repo
```

means that you tell your system to see if there is a package called `repo` and install it if it can find it. Since there is no package `repo` the notice you get is

```
E: Unable to locate package repo
```

So this is normal!

Answer (score 2):

As Rinzwind explains, there is no package called `repo` so Ubuntu cannot install it. If you are not sure about the existence of a package, run the following command to check whether it can be found:

```
apt-cache search [packageName]
```

In your case that would be `apt-cache search repo`. In this particular case you will get a great many results because *repo* is short for *repository* which is part of many package names.

Feel free to ask another question to get help on what you are more specifically installing.

Comment: https://source.android.com/setup/develop#installing-repo  check what google tells.

Answer (score 0):

Type in your commandline

```
apt policy | grep universe
```

If you got no result, you have probably not enabled the Universe packages.
To do so,

- **open software** and
- in the menu **Software & Updates**
- enable **Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)** .

Afterwards refresh your apt-cache by

```
sudo apt update
```

Now you are ready to install **repo**

```
sudo apt install repo
```

Comment: This doesn't help.